# Watson generated Pytorch results in: "ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list"

Tags: python, code-generation, conv-neural-network, pytorch, ibm-watson

I am experimenting Watson Neural Network Modeler.

I've create a model from the built in demo "Single Convolution layer on MNIST". The only customization I did was to specify the training data files.

[image]

I then exported the Pytorch code and I am trying to run in on my local computer.

The generated code is pretty readable. The relevant code excerpt is:

```python
# Define network architecture
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inp_c):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, ImageData_4, target):

        Convolution2D_9 = self.Convolution2D_9(ImageData_4)
        ReLU_1 = self.ReLU_1(Convolution2D_9)
        Pooling2D_8 = self.Pooling2D_8(ReLU_1)
        Flatten_2 = Pooling2D_8.view(-1, 10816)
        Dense_3 = self.Dense_3(Flatten_2)
        Softmax_5 = self.Softmax_5(Dense_3)
        Accuracy_6 = torch.topk(Softmax_5, 1)[0]
        CrossEntropyLoss_7 = self.CrossEntropyLoss_7(Softmax_5, target)
        return Softmax_5, Accuracy_6

# Model Initialization
inp_c = 1
model = Net(inp_c)
model.cuda()

# Define optimizer
learning_rate = 0.001000
decay = 0.000000
beta_1 = 0.900000
beta_2 = 0.999000
optim = optim.Adam(
    model.parameters(),
    lr=learning_rate,
    betas=(beta_1, beta_2),
    weight_decay=decay)
```

I am getting the error:

```python
"ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list"
```

on the `optim = optim.Adam()` statement.

Is there any Watson user/expert over there to bring some light on this issue? I am basically running the demo. It was not supposed to fail.

Thanks!

Comment: There is clearly a problem with the generated code, as the `Net` layers attributes (`self.Convolution2D_9`, `self.ReLU_1`, etc.) are defined nowhere (should typically be in `Net.__init__()`). I've however never used Watson, so no idea why the omission...

Comment: thats true. It is not defined on the Net class and obviously is not defined on nn.Module